# how to link a hover button

Tags: html, css

I found some html and css that produces some nice hover buttons that I'd like to use.  I was able to change the button text to be relevant to my site.
All I need to do is make these buttons link to he desired pages.

1. I've tried simply looking for the example link and substituting mine.
2. I've tried adding a basic html line of link code in many places in the sample code.
3. I've created similar buttons with Expression Web's "Interactive Button" generator but have never been able to modify them.

That generator asks where the link should go and I input it and it works.  I've never reverse engineered it to understand how to modify it.  I just delete it and start over. This is it: http://boundtotease.com/testing/index3.html

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please post the relevant code, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: please isolate the problematic code (the buttons in your case) and post them in your question. your question is way off topic on stack overflow. should the link to your website change or go down in the future, your question will become useless and will most likely get deleted.

Comment: I don't know enough about the code problem to even know where to post it.  Sorry to be way off topic, Is there a place where I can ask which forum I belong in before I bother the relevant helpers?  I guess that's not here so I'll keep looking for the correct forum.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<button onclick="window.location='http://www.naveedramzan.com'">Click Me</button>
```